# Memory leak when sorting array

Tags: objective-c

I have the following function

```
- (NSArray *) getUsers : (days) aDay {

    NSArray *arr = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (User *e in [week objectAtIndex:aDay]) {
        //Get distance to user
        e.place.distance = [[LocationManager sharedLocationManager] getDistanceWithLat:e.place.latitude Lon:e.place.longitude];
    }

    //Sort the array
    arr = [ [week objectAtIndex:aDay] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
            User *e1 = (User *)obj1;
            User *e2 = (User *)obj2;

            if (e1.place.distance <= e2.place.distance) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            } else {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    [arr retain];

    return arr;
}
```

It leaks and I can't figure out how to fix it. If I remove [arr retian] then the application crash.

When I preform action profile the instruments display a leak of 100% on this line:

```
   arr = [ [week objectAtIndex:aDay] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
```

How could I fix this leak?

Comment: Is it a normal casting `User *e1 = (Event *)obj1;`?

Comment: @beryllium no, updated the post. Messed it up while I was trying some stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `NSArray *arr = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];` and `[arr retain];` at all. In first line you allocated memory, but when sorting you refer to new array and got leak.

```
NSArray *arr = [ [week objectAtIndex:aDay] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
            User *e1 = (User *)obj1;
            User *e2 = (User *)obj2;

            if (e1.place.distance <= e2.place.distance) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            } else {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];

return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a retained object: `arr`. Methods returning retain objectets Objective-C naming rules just start with `new`, or contain the word `copy`.

There is no need to alloc/init `arr`, the `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method will return an autoreleased `NSArray`.

Do not name method with the prefix "get" unless they return results via a reference parameter. This is basic Objective-C naming rules and ARC relies on naming rules being adhered to.

See Apple's documentation [Introduction to Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: By removing the retain I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: The caller needs to retain the returned value it it wants to keep it. It would be well worth the time to study Objective-C memory management. Also, use ARC. Write no line of code you do not fully understand what it does and why it is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, priceless.